# How to stop fetching collections in backbone

Tags: backbone.js

Disk is my collections object. I need to stop fetching collections

```
customPoll: function(time){
          var set_time = 0;
            if(time === undefined){
                set_time = 4000;
            }
            var route = Backbone.history.fragment.split('/');
            var self = this;
            if(route[0] === "disks"){
                setTimeout(function() {
                    Disks.fetch({update:true,success: function(){
                        self.customPoll();
                    }, error: function(){
                        self.customPoll();
                    }
                    });
                }, set_time); //TODO Need to handle efficiently...
            }  
        }
```

Am trying to call this fetching in every 4 second if some condition exist other wise i need to stop calling this fetching.

```
    var route = Backbone.history.fragment.split('/');
            var smart = new Smart.model({
                "id"    : route[1]
            });
            var self = this;
    smart.save(null,{
                    success: function(model,event,response){
                        model =  Disks.get(route[1]).toJSON();
                        $('#smart-confirm-dialog').modal('hide'); 
                        self.showStatusMsg(1,"<b> S.M.A.R.T. Test : </b>S.M.A.R.T Test started succesfully");
                        if(model.smart.progress === "100%"){
                            self.clearAllTimeout();
                            alert("please stop fetching....pleaseeee");
                            // Stop polling here . then fetch information from smart.fetch api.
                           Smart.fetch({update: true}); //this is another api i need to call this api now.
                        }else{
                            self.customPoll();
                        }
});
```

But it seems to be not working... Its keep on fetching collection.. How can i stop this Disk collection fetching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer maybe is funny, I want to add comment, but I couldn't. can you add new field to your model and

```
customPoll: function(time){
   var  disks = this.model.toJSON();
   if(disks.yourField){
       // here your code
   }
}
```

but before saving the model need to do  `delete disks.yourField;`